# How to secure a fastapi app hosted on EC2 instance with a self-signed SSL certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, openssl, fastapi

I have a Fastapi app hosted on EC2 instance using `docker-compose.yml`. Currently, the app is not secured (HTTP & not HTTPS). I am trying to secure the app via a self-signed cert by following the tutorial [Deploy your FastAPI API to AWS EC2 using Nginx](https://lcalcagni.medium.com/deploy-your-fastapi-to-aws-ec2-using-nginx-aa8aa0d85ec7).

I have the following in the `fastapi_nginx` file in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    server_name x.xx.xxx.xxx;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000/docs;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. When I do `https://x.xx.xxx.xxx`, I get the error:

> This page isn’t working
>
> x.xx.xxx.xxx didn’t send any data.
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

But `http://x.xx.xxx.xxx` is working like before.

I am not sure if I am missing anything or making any mistakes.

P.S.: I also tried doing the steps mentioned in the article [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html) and still it wasn't working.

Also, the inbound in security groups

[image]

Comment: What's the value in using a self-signed cert? Wouldn't a Let's Encrypt cert be better?

Comment: @halfer It is just for testing purposes. Since I am learning how to do it, I started with the tutorials from AWS which used self signed certs

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting https traffic to /docs, have you tried `proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;`?

Also 0.0.0.0 is not always a good solution, it means to all IP addresses on the local machine as referred [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1). Try 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

You can check any errors in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Finally, see if your security group and route table allow the traffic.

Comment: I tried without `/docs`, but still, it doesn't work. Also, it didn't open when I tried to access `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Comment: You should keep it without /docs, until you get it working. 
For the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` you would need to add `error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log  warn;` inside your nginx configuration file and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you make use of the `docker-compose.yml`. You can probably configure as follows:

###### Extend your `docker-compose.yml` having nginx as well.

In the below mounts the `nginx.conf` is the file you have defined locally, certs are certificates. Also, it would be best to keep in the same network as per the fastapi app so that they communicate.

`nginx.conf` to be modified is to point to the Docker service name of the fastapi app:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://my-fastapi-app:8000/docs;
}
```

An example snippet below:

```
...
networks:
  app_net:
    services:
      my-fastapi-app:
        ...
        networks:
         - app_net
      nginx:
        image: 'bitnami/nginx:1.14.2'
        ports:
          - '80:8080'
          - '443:8443'
        volumes:
          - ./nginx.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
          - ./certs:/opt/bitnami/nginx/certs/:ro
          - ./tmp/:/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/:rw
        networks:
         - app_net
```

Additionally, I could also suggest looking into caddy. The certification process and renewal is automatically done.